# Missing Users table in drupal mysql backup database

Tags: mysql, drupal

I migrated a backed up database into a new drupal installation but the mysql database does not have the "Users" table. Is there a reason to why a drupal mysql backup might not have the Users table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check backup migrate settings on "Advanced Backup" page.
Look at the "Default Database Backup Options" fieldset and check options selected "Exclude the data from the following tables" maybe Users table was checked there and this could be the reason why you don't have this table.